# VS Code - Change the background color of selected item in suggestion widget

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start typing code in my file, VS Code's IntelliSense will open a suggestion widget window. However, my color scheme does not highlight which item I'm currently selecting.

For example, in my screenshot below, I'm currently selecting the 2nd item (`position`) after pressing my Tab key once, but this item has the same background color as other unselected items. How can I change the background color of the selected item?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, I want to change the colors of this pop-up list so that you can clearly see what I choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Command Palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and run it. This should open `settings.json` in a new window.

   [image: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)]
3. Add the following new property into your `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "[YOUR_COLOR_SCHEME_NAME]": {
        "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#ff00005e"
     }
   },
   ```

   Replace `YOUR_COLOR_SCHEME_NAME` with the name of the color scheme you are using. For example, if my color scheme is called "Monokai Pro", I write `"[Monokai Pro]": {` in the second line.

In the 3rd line, I chose the color `#ff00005e` (red color with some transparency) as the background of the highlighted list item. It would then look something like:

[image: highlighted item]

Feel free to change the color `#ff0005e` to any color you like :)

Comment: nicely explained Sir - nice to customize my NotepadPlusPlus Remixed Theme